# Writing a function in R to compute 95% CI

Tags: r, statistics

Given X1, X2, ..., Xn independent r.v from a Normal(mu, sigma^2) distribution, where sigma^2 is a unknown, I need to write a function that computes a 95% confidence interval for mu. It should be a function of n and sigma. I know how to calculate confidence intervals, but not sure how to write a function like

```
f <- function(...) { ... }
```

that computes 95% CI that runs when compiling a report. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

The code I have made is

```
    # data("dataframe")
    # dataframe <- b
    # xbar <- mean(b$x) # taking the mean
    # n<- length(b$x)
    # sd <- sd(b$x)
    # se <- sd/sqrt(n)
    
    
    
    # alpha <- 0.05
    # d_f <- n-1
    # t <- qt(p = alpha/2, df = d_f, lower.tail = FALSE)
    
    # m <- t*se
    # L <- xbar - m
    # U <- xbar + m
    
    # print(c(L, U))
```

Comment: If you know how to write the code but not how to embed it in a function, can you show us the code that you would use if you had a vector `X` in your global environment?

Comment: I have edited post

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have n, mean and sd you can do this

```
f95 <- function(n, mean, sd) {
  e <- qnorm(0.975)*sd/sqrt(n)
  return(c("lower" = mean - e, "upper" = mean + e))
}

f95(n = 30, mean = 12, sd = 3)

#  lower  upper 
# 10.926 13.074
```

Comment: It's assuming sigma is unknown